# Problema datetime valor null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

resulta que cuando ejecuto mi vista, me da este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora bien, mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
        public ActionResult contact(string txtNombreArchivo, string txtCantidadTarjetas, string txtNombreAfiliado, string txtBIN, DateTime dtpFechaVigencia, string txtTextoMonto, string txtMonto, string btnSubmit)
    {
        BC.Funciones funciones = new Funciones();
        DAC.Axon bd = new DAC.Axon();
            try
            {

                if (!Directory.Exists(@"Respaldo"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"Respaldo");
                }

                funciones.EscribirCSV("Numero Afiliado;Cuenta;Clave;Vigencia;Nombre afiliado;Texto;Track1 Banda;Track2 Banda;EAN13;BIN", int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString()), txtNombreArchivo.ToString());
                Random rnd = new Random();

                int consecutivo = 1;
                int random9 = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999);

                int rowcount = int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString());



                TarjetaTicket[] tarjetaTickets = new TarjetaTicket[int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString())];
                for (int i = 0; i <= rowcount - 1; i++)
                {
                    BC.TarjetaTicket tarjetaTicket = new TarjetaTicket();
                    int nro1 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int nro2 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int clave = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
                    int quince1 = rnd.Next(10000000, 99999999);
                    int quince2 = rnd.Next(1000000, 9999999);

                    string Track1 = "B" + nro1 + nro2 + "^    /                     ^" + random9.ToString();
                    string Track2 = nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString() + "=" + quince1 + quince2;
                    funciones.EscribirCSV(consecutivo.ToString("0000") + ";" + nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString() + ";" + clave + ";" + dtpFechaVigencia.Date.ToString().Substring(0, 10) +
                        ";" + txtNombreAfiliado.ToString() + ";" + txtTextoMonto.ToString() + ";" + Track1 + ";" + Track2 + ";" + nro1 + nro2.ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ";" + txtBIN.ToString(), int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString()), txtNombreArchivo.ToString());
                    consecutivo++;


                    tarjetaTicket.NumeroTarjeta = nro1.ToString() + nro2.ToString();
                    tarjetaTicket.FechaCreacionTarjeta = DateTime.Now;
                    tarjetaTicket.FechaVigenciaTarjeta = dtpFechaVigencia;
                    tarjetaTicket.MontoTarjeta = txtMonto.ToString();
                    tarjetaTicket.HashOriginal = rnd.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();

                    tarjetaTickets[i] = tarjetaTicket;
                }


                BC.Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
                ticket.NombreTicket = txtNombreArchivo.ToString();
                ticket.Bin = txtBIN.ToString();
                ticket.TotalTarjetas = int.Parse(txtCantidadTarjetas.ToString());
                ticket.FechaCreacionTicket = DateTime.Now;
                ticket.NombreAfiliado = txtNombreAfiliado.ToString();


            }

            catch (Exception ron)
            {
                Exception ex;
                //MessageBox.Show(ron.Message);
            }

            return View(funciones);
        }




    private void EscribirCSV(string mensaje, int cantidad, string txtNombreArchivo)

    {
        //Método utilizado para probar
        //NO SE SI ESTA BIEN
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"Respaldo" + "\\" + "F28112018_123456_T_789456_" + txtNombreArchivo.ToString() + "_" + cantidad + "_12345678" + ".csv");
        streamWriter.WriteLine(mensaje);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

esta es mi vi

```html
<body>
</body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="~/Home/contact" />
    <form method="post">
        <div>Nombre archivo</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtNombreArchivo" class="form-control" /></div>
        <div>Cantidad tarjetas</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtCantidadTarjetas" class="form-control"/></div>
        <div>nombre Afiliado</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtNombreAfiliado"class="form-control" /></div>
        <div>BIN</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtBIN"class="form-control" /></div>
        <div>fecha vigencia</div>
        <div><input type="date" name="dtpFechaVigencia"class="form-control"/></div>
        <div>monto</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtMonto" class="form-control"/></div>
        <div>textmonto</div>
        <div><input type="text" name="txtTextoMonto"class="form-control" /></div>
        <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="agregar" />
    </form>
</div>
```

sta

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

El primero problema que veo es que defines dos tags `form` cuando deberia ser

```
<form action="~/Home/contact" method="post" >
```

ademas el primero form lo estas cerrando con la / y en el segundo solo defines el method

Por otro lado no deberias poner txt o dpt, etc en los controles, eso es muy de asp.net clasico, no se usa en asp.net mvc.

El btnSubmit no tienes de definirlo, no se define el boton como parte de los parametros, este solo realiza la accion y nada mas

Ademas cuando tienes muchos parametro deberias definir un model en una clase y no cada parametro

```
public class ContactModel
{
    public string txtNombreArchivo {get;set;}
    public string txtCantidadTarjetas {get;set;}
    public string txtNombreAfiliado {get;set;}
    public string txtBIN {get;set;}
    public DateTime dtpFechaVigencia {get;set;}
    public string txtTextoMonto {get;set;}
    public string txtMonto {get;set;}
}
```

en el action usarias

```
public ActionResult contact(ContactModel model)
{
   //resto codigo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para ese caso puedes añadir una validacion. pEjm:

```
if(dtpFechaVigencia != null)
{
  tarjetaTicket.FechaVigenciaTarjeta = dtpFechaVigencia;
}
```

en caso de ser ese valor null, evitas ese error

Comment: Lo habia intentado y no funciono, mejor me cambie rapido para asp.net jeje, gracias!